# What kind of game is it ? A political Game with infinite loss

Tags: game-theory

I have thought about a game, however I don't really any "famous game" from the game that could illustrate this situation. I would be interested by any kind of reference about it.

The rules:
The participants need to collaborate in order to keep a critical system working. Each turn, a certain amount of dollar is required to keep the system properly working. If the participants can't agree on how to pay the bill, the system break and everyone loose everything.

The individual goal is to pay the least as possible each turn for anything and profit from the others paying for the maintainance fees.

And of course the objective is to never end the game. The only solution to end it, is that every participants loose everything.

How would you describe such a system when the loss is infinite if the game stops, and the loss finite to keep it working.

Another version of this game could be a finite gain to share each month, if participants don't agree then everyone loose everything.

---

For what I know in the game theory, this game has the following characterics:

- Cooperative Game
- A Non-Zero Sum Game
- Infinite Game and Finite Game (The Game should continue forever, except if participants fail to find an agreement).

Bonus Question: How would you call this game in the most "game theory" way?

I just didn't find anything about a game with infine gain/loss. I would be very grateful for any reading recommendation.

Comment: May be trivial but: the game is: "non-Sequential"(or "simultaneous"), "Nash equilibrium"(if the system is set, no one will change anything). We can't tell from the given rules if the game is perfect information, if everyone know everyone's starting point/finite gain then it is a perfect information game, it is also "asymmetric" game,  "non-combinatorial game"(there is no winning condition, only loss), "continuous game", honestly I don't know if this game is "differential game" from the given rules, "population game"(assuming that there is finite number of players,otherwise everyone will pay 0)

Comment: Continuing from my previous comment: no enough information to say of it is "metagame". I have no idea how to formally represent this game

Comment: You may be interested in "Gale–Stewart games"